# Why I can not connect these nodes from different networks?

Tags: networking

I have this graph:

[image: click here]

I managed to make `PC1A` ping `PC2A`, they are in the same network but I have to make `PC1A` ping `PC1B` and I can't.

I did this:

[image: click here]

Why I can not ping them? What kind of routing should I use?

Comment: You will need to build static routes in the various routers... what are the WAN interface IP's of the various routers? and what make/model routers (some don't do static routes very well)?

Comment: I am not sure if I can answer your question. All I know is that I have to use either default, host or network route. For example, "route add 172.16.1.1 gw 192.168.1.254"(host route)

Comment: No, you need to add the subnet... For example, in AC there would need to be a route like "route 172.16.1.0/24 via gw 192.168.1.254" (the exact command may vary) but basically you need to tell the router the subnet is reachable via router AC's WAN (eth1) IP address, and you need a route in reverse in BC. And this is just to talk to the other subnet, you would need a rule for each subnet and a default gateway. Again, this process varies and you are not giving sufficient information to formulate an answer.

Comment: Not sure if the route table will make it more clear http://prntscr.com/jkbi3o

Comment: So you are trying to control the routing at the PC level? Than  you need a route back from PC1A. Sorry, I am getting more confused... What are the .254 addresses? You have a 172.16.1.254 defined as a the default gateway in PC1B, but your network diagram does not show that IP anywhere. Again, your network diagram is missing critical information, specifically the IP addresses of the various interfaces on each router.

Comment: The task: http://prntscr.com/jkbmk8
http://prntscr.com/jkbmvh
Table with IP's http://prntscr.com/jkbmvh as PC1A has 10.1.0.1/16, PC2A has 10.1.0.2/16 and RouterAC has 10.1.0.3/16 eth0 but for eth1 it is 192.168.1.4/24.
Useful info:
http://prntscr.com/jkbnu1
http://prntscr.com/jkbo0s

Comment: RouterBC has 172.16.1.3 eth0 and eth1 is 192.168.1.3/24 ,  pc1b is 172.16.1.1/24 and pc2b is 172.16.1.2/24. LANC does not have a  router and they have 192.168.1.0/24  as a network. PC1C has 192.168.1.1/24 and PC2C has 192.168.1.2/24

Comment: I think Gateaways is not nedeed now.

Comment: So this is a homework assignment? Perhaps ask some classmates or your teacher... Hmm... I think I will bow out here